# "from cplex import *" command get an Error in VScode saying "... mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cplex, arm64, docplex

Thank you in advance for your kind support
I installed the CPLEX academic version to solve a MIP model using Docplex in the VScode editor (using Python 3.10.4 64-bit).
However, can't run it and getting the following error for this line: "from cplex import *":

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cplex/_internal/py310_cplex2210.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cplex/_internal/py310_cplex2210.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
  File "/Users/masoud/Desktop/Python-cplex/Pricing-h_g-w_pgijk-g2.py", line 8, in <module>
```

Can anyone advise me to handle this problem?

Comment: Can you control what is invoked on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

The `.so` (library) file that Python is trying to open is built for macOS, but for x86_64 (Intel) hardware. You appear to be using a Mac with Apple's M1 architecture, which is incompatible with x86_64 machine code. You need to download the source of the `cplex` package, install XCode and the command-line tools, and re-build the library using the `arm64e` architecture, or as a "universal" binary.

Alternately, if the source is not available, check the vendor's website to see if they have any macOS "universal" builds available. If not, write to their tech support!

**EDIT**

I've done some research, and it does not appear that an M1 version is available from IBM. I would try to contact them or post in their community forum and push for an Apple Silicon port.